# Getting segfault when installing Landscape Dedicated Server

Tags: 14.04, server, juju, openstack, landscape

I am trying to set up Landscape on a *DigitalOcean VPS* (14.04) and at the very end of the install I get a `segfault`. I'm new to landscape so I might struggle. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Web browser with Landscape on my VPS, and the SSH terminal.]

Here's the code from the terminal when installing to the VPS:

```
 * Starting Landscape standalone message-server 1                        [ OK ] 
 * Checking database schema                                              [ OK ] 
 * Starting Landscape standalone pingserver 1                            [ OK ] 
 * Checking database schema                                              [ OK ] 
 * Starting Landscape standalone api 1                                          /opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/landscape-env.sh: line 187: 10380 Segmentation fault  (core dumped) LANDSCAPE_CONFIG="$LANDSCAPE_CONFIG-$instance" start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid $LSUSER --exec $LSROOT/$SCRIPT $background -- --rundir=$LSROOT --pidfile=$pidfile
                                                                         [fail]
 * Checking database schema                                              [ OK ] 
 * Starting Landscape standalone package-upload 1                               /opt/canonical/landscape/scripts/landscape-env.sh: line 187: 10467 Segmentation fault  LANDSCAPE_CONFIG="$LANDSCAPE_CONFIG-$instance" start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid $LSUSER --exec $LSROOT/$SCRIPT $background -- --rundir=$LSROOT --pidfile=$pidfile
                                                                         [fail]
 * Checking database schema                                              [fail] 
ERROR:root:Traceback (most recent call last):
Error verifying schema
landscape-package-search stop/pre-start, process 10539
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ...
root@landscape-sgp1-01:~#
```

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: I have never seen this.  Taking a wild guess -- how much memory do you have?  Could you examine or post the corefile somewhere?